# User online status in php/JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have website where I want to show user online status. Currently I am using JQuery function to update on database and to get online status in every 5 seconds. here is function:

```
setInterval(function() { 
update_online_status();
},5000);
```

is there any better solution so i will not need to deal with database, something like session or cookies. I want this solution to scale the website.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just checking the current user, then session and cookie variables would work.

But I would assume you are checking other users' online statuses. In this case you have the best solution. Just try and find a good interval to update at (I like 5000, just like you already have). Using session and cookie variables would still require database interaction since you can not know about other users directly.

That being said, to update the current users information, you don't need to check at any interval; you just need to listen for when a user logs in or out, and call a database interaction at that moment.

This is how [my current project](http://www.ameraudio.com/fix) does log-ins/-outs. I update the database on login, so it is available to other users. And do the same when they logout. I use ajax to make the transition fluid and non-blocking.

Comment: what if user didnt click on logout. Just close the browser?

Comment: You can check for that with jQuery as well. Check out [`unload()`](http://api.jquery.com/unload/)

Comment: what if user directly restarted the machine... without any event,

Comment: In that case, I don't know if the OS will call the quit functions for each application (it depends on which OS it is), but it might handle it. This is more of a server-side communication than a client-side one. I'll have to think about how best to do this.

Comment: As far as the user not logging out explicitly or being able to capture the unload() event, I've used a setup in the past where we log the user's last interaction time with the server and have a cron job running server-side which checks that time periodically and manually "logs out" the user server side if no activity has been recorded after some period of time.